# Build Test Artifacts from a Multistage Docker Build in Jenkins - Is there any way to upload to the job workspace from inside Docker build?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to access a build artifact made during docker build from Jenkins. I.e. code coverage reports, unit test outputs, etc.

I have already considered:
- Multiple docker files
- Not removing intermediate build containers (seems 'hacky' to me)

I am wondering if inside the dockerfile I could possibly `curl` upload the relevant build artifacts *to the current jenkins job's workspace from within the dockerfile* while it is running.

Does anyone have any insight into whether this is possible?

Comment: same doubt here